# Horizontal scrollbars after adding overlay on background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working through a tutorial and creating the "Getting started" section shown in the image below:

[image]

I notice that as soon as I add the CSS for the dark-overlay class, I start getting these horizontal scrollbars. I have checked by commenting out the dark-overlay css and the scrollbars have disappeared.

Here's my code:

```
<section id="home-heading" class="p-5">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container pt-5">
            <h1>Are You Ready To Get Started?</h1>
            <p class="d-none d-md-block">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est eaque magni sit dolores. Nisi, dolor nam modi perspiciatis
              consequatur soluta.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

and the CSS:

```
#home-heading {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/lights.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.dark-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

If the overlay css is causing the problem, why so, because the parent element #home-heading is positioned relative, so the dark-overlay class should be positioned relative to the parent?

Can someone help point out what is happening?

Thanks,
Sohaib

Comment: The scrollbars can occur if your child element exceeds the width/height of parent element. Can you try removing the height/width from your dark-overlay class ?

Comment: @wahabmemon how will that make a difference? Width and height are set to 100% of the parent element, which is the home-heading area...

Answer (score 1):

Try remove row and col divs.
.row and .col tends to add unwanted paddings.

Comment: Hi @BitAtWork, thank you. This sems to have worked. However, in this particular case, the row and col classes weren't particularly needed. What if we need that setup? What is the way to avoid the scrollbars then?

A way is to set ```overflow-x: hidden``` on the body but doesn't sit well with me. Seems more like a hack than a proper fix... Thoughts?

Comment: If you really need row and col, you'll have to remove the unwanted padding/marging with extra styling. no-gutters (as you self wrote) might help. You may also use the overflow-x: hidden on body and then have a container with overflow instead. But that depends on how you want to handle any overflows.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, in case anyone stumbles across such a scenario in the future, turns out the bootstrap .col and .row classes indeed add unwanted padding.

Now in a scenario identical to the ones I posted here, a simple fix will be to just remove the row and col classes from the markup. If you're looking for something other than that, one of the following approaches might work:

1)

```
#home-heading .row, #home-heading .col{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

This explicitly removes the margin and padding from the said classes

2. Add the `no-gutters` class to the row, as in:

```
<section id="home-heading" class="p-5">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container pt-5">
            <h1>Are You Ready To Get Started?</h1>
            <p class="d-none d-md-block">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est eaque magni sit dolores. Nisi, dolor nam modi perspiciatis
              consequatur soluta.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

This removes the padding (AKA spacing) that the BS grid includes by default.
Sohaib